# Cannot display data from table where table column name starts with a number codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I want to display data from a table where the column name starts with a number, here is the code in view file inside the loop

```
<?php echo $cus->3rdfloorslab; ?>
```

it shows me the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or
>   T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in
>   C:\wamp\www\westlinecrm\application\views\client\addpaymentstatementform.php
>   on line 318

is there any solution to display the data without changing the column name from numeric to string.

Comment: It's not best practice to use this kind of names for column. Pls check this: http://justinsomnia.org/2003/04/essential-database-naming-conventions-and-style/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use the following

```
<?php echo $cus->{'3rdfloorslab'}; ?>
```

[Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) is some documentation on variable parsing. Though it's not the best practice.

If you're getting the data from a database, you could do something like

```
SELECT 3rdfloorslab AS thirdfloorslab
```

Which would help keep your code to the same standard.